# Function to make an array of strings using data from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'e an array of objects that I want to get information (emails) from and store to a new array from.

I've tried several times but can't quite get this to work.

My most recent attempt is:

```
function getAllCustomerEmails(data) {
    let emailArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        return data[i].email;
    }
}
```

What else do I need to do/what am I doing wrong here?

I was able to get all the emails to appear with a console log but can't quite get it to return as a string or get it saved to the array.

Comment: A function only returns _once_. And if you want to create an array from an array, with the same length, think `.map`.

Comment: `data.map(d => d.email)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You weren't pushing anything to your array, you have to push `email` values to your array while inside the loop and return the array once after the loop has finished.

**Note**: I'm using a mock array of objects here since I don't know how your array looks like.

```js
const array = [{
    userName: "name1",
    email: "usermail1@gmail.com"
},{
    userName: "name2",
    email: "usermail2@gmail.com"
},{
    userName: "name3",
    email: "usermail3@gmail.com"
}];

function getAllCustomerEmails(data) {
  let emailArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     emailArray.push(data[i].email);
  }
  return emailArray;
}

console.log(getAllCustomerEmails(array));
```

Another option using `.map()`

```js
const array = [{
    userName: "name1",
    email: "usermail1@gmail.com"
},{
    userName: "name2",
    email: "usermail2@gmail.com"
},{
    userName: "name3",
    email: "usermail3@gmail.com"
}];

const result = array.map(x =>{
    return x.email;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: a simple `map` would suffice here... `const getAllCustomerEmails(data) => data.map(v => v.email);`

Comment: Yes, just wanted to explain the reason why his function wasn't working

Comment: BTW, if you just `return` you can omit the `{}` and the `return` keyword itself, and just write `x => x.email`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInfo(data) {
    let emailArray = [];
    //looping the array of obj
    data.forEach(obj => {
        emailArray.push(obj.email);
    });
    return emailArray;
}


let obj = [
    {
    name:"XYZ",
    email:"abc@xyz.com"
},
    {
    name:"ABC",
    email:"LMN@xyz.com"
},
    {
    name:"XYZ",
    email:"ads@xyz.com"
},
    {
    name:"XYZ",
    email:"tyfh@xyz.com"
},
]
//passing an array of object
let result = getInfo(obj);
console.log(result);
```

Here,  i have given an hardcoded array of object according to your need and then looped it and used push() method of array to add elements into it.
So, i have added all the emails from the respective objects and returned the new array.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
const data = [{name: "one", email: "one"},{name: "two", email: "two"}]

function getAllCustomerEmails(data) {
  let emailArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    emailArray.push(data[i].email);
}
    return emailArray;
}

getAllCustomerEmails(data)
```

Comment: 1st option, no different from existing answer. 2nd option bad usage of `.map` method

Comment: Instead of map you should use forEach method as map function has other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the first object in the list your are looping through instead of pushing (adding) each item in to your email array  and then return the email array. So the function will end on the first object instead of when the list has be loop through. I will try to demonstrate.

This is your array of objects:

| obj | obj | obj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [z@gmail.com] | [x@gmail.com] | [y@gmail.com] |
| index 0 | index 1 | index 2 |

So a array with objects that all contains a list (email).

Each time that you your are looping through list you wanna access that list.

At 0 you wanna get z@gmail.com etc.

When you are doing this:

```js
function getAllCustomerEmails(data) {
  let emailArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    return data[i].email;
 }
}
```

You are saying only return the **first element** and when you have done that **end the loop**. So the first element in the list will be obj with [z@gmail.com]. With the index 0. And then the loop will end.

So what do we need to change or add?

We know that the condition is right but we wanna return a list of element and not only one like we are doing now. So we need to add something or **push** the each item in the list. **Emailarray** list.

And to do that:

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    emailArray.push(data[i].email);
  }
```

Which means that each time the index increase and point on a "new item" in the array then we will "go in that object" so we can access the **email** and then add it to the email list.

First time  [z@gmail.com]

Second time [x@gmail.com]

Third time [y@gmail.com]

Then when the loop is done will we return the array with emails:

```js
function getAllCustomerEmails(data) {
  let emailArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    emailArray.push(data[i].email);
  }
  return emailArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ES6 way to do this would be to use `map` as in:

```
const objArray = [
{name: 'bob', email: 'bobs@email.com'},
{name: 'bobette', email: 'bobettes@email.com'},
]

const arrayOfEmails = objArray.map(obj => obj.email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Embrace the `Array.protoype.map` function to solve such problems

```js
const toEmail = ({email}) => email;
const getAllCustomerEmails = array => array.map(toEmail);
console.log(getAllCustomerEmails([{email: "ele@email.com", foo: "bar"}, {email: "ele2@email.com", foo2: "bar2"}]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```